# Splitting an ID column based on ID + Phase of sample

Tags: r, tidyverse

data =

`data.frame ( ID = c('101 1h','101 2h','101 3h','102 1h','102 2h','102 3h'), marker1 = c(1,1,2,2,2,3), marker2 = c(3,3,4,5,5,6)))`

I would like to split the data into rows with just ID number and then three columns for each phase with its respective marker1 and marker2 result.

For example the first row should be ID = 101, phase = 1h, biomarker1 = 1,biomarker2 = 3

I have tried first separate() the ID column into ID number and phase. Then using the new phase column in a spread() command. The spread command however for each correct answer in for example column 1h, i would have two NA's in columns 2h and 3h. So if someone knows how to solve this i would love to hear.

Thank you.

Update: I think i realized my mistake, i was probably supposed to use gather() instead of spread().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks fairly straightforward with a combination of `separate` and `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`

```r
library(tidyr)

separate(data, ID, c('ID', 'phase')) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = 'phase', values_from = c('marker1', 'marker2'))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 7
#>   ID    marker1_1h marker1_2h marker1_3h marker2_1h marker2_2h marker2_3h
#>   <chr>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1 101            1          1          2          3          3          4
#> 2 102            2          2          3          5          5          6
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer that solved my problem perfectly. This seems to be a rather simple thing for you, do you have recommendations on where i can go to get these "basics" down, im thinking courses and the like.

Comment: @HenrikOde I have never been on an R course, and though some books are helpful, such as the free online [R for Data science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/index.html), I have found that I learn most by trying to work on real problems, reading the help files and scouring Stack Overflow when I am stuck. If it helps, it took me quite a while to get my head around `pivot_wider` and `pivot_longer`!